# Angular router: Displaying children horizontal (as siblings)

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-animations

I would like to achieve the following behaviour:

Routes:

- /
  [ROOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtFrL.png)
- /patients
  [PANEL1 depth-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnnXk.png)
- /patients/1
  [PANEL2 depth-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ODsp.png)
- /patients/1/log
  [PANEL3 depth-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEi4d.png)

I would like to have following routing definition:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'patients',
    component: PatientsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: PatientsListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: PatientDetailsComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'log',
                component: PatientLogComponent,
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

If I do that DOM structure is nested ... Is it possible to open children horizontally (sibling like)? Further on I would also like to enable animations so that if depth is more than 3 first panels width will collapse ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this is possible, i make same app as your

- Root Component (after auth or anything else)
- - Left menu
- - Route outlet
- - - PatientsComponent
- - - Route outlet
- - - - PatientsListComponent (route outlet or ngIf with url parameter in template)
- - - - Route outlet
- - - - - PatientDetailsComponent (route outlet or ngIf with url parameter in template)

and deeper and deeper

than u write router u use same components in depth

routing like your, but PatientList in my case not exist, i render  in PatientComponent

**RootComponent:**

  `<app-menu></app-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**PatientComponent:**

`<app-list></app-list>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**PatientDetailsComponent:**

`<app-data>DETAIL DATA HERE</app-data>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

same deeper and deeper

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Can you maybe provide some sample?